# Date.getTimezoneOffset returns wrong results?

Tags: javascript

Tested for Brasilian Time Zone. Change it on your system if you are not from Brasil.
Here is the code:

```
var b = new Date(2013, 9, 20, 0, 0, 0);
var bt = b.getTime();
var bof = b.getTimezoneOffset(); // in hours
var m = 60*1000; // minutes * miliseconds

var utctime1 = bt - bof*m;
var utctime2 = Date.UTC(2013, 9, 20, 0, 0, 0);

return utctime1 == utctime2;
```

returns false, meaning the timestamps are different.

Upon further investigation, it seems that for 20.10.2013 0:00 JS returns timestamp for one time zone but the timezoneOffset for the other one.
Is there really an error or I am making something / thinking wrong?

Comment: *returns false, meaning the timestamps are different.* That only means the they aren't the same object. Use `console.log()` to dump both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/zudfB/ Says it's `true` here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: it doesn't matter, these are integers

Comment: @Allendar: please test it in browser's console

Comment: Did you even look at my link? My code *does* test it in the Browser's Console, and it returns `true`.

Comment: @Allendar: did you change to brasilian time zone? AND restarted the browser?

Comment: [comment from deleted answer] _“It seems like getTimezoneOffset doesn't know that DST starts.”_ – well, _has_ it already started at 00:00 hours?